# Is this Code Exploitable? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I paid someone to code basic PHP scripts for me, so bare in mind for my dumb questions. I just want to keep my users safe.

Is this code exploitable, and if so, how can I fix it?

```
if(isset($_POST['serial'])){
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $count=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE serial=:serial LIMIT 1");
    $count->bindParam(":serial",$serial);
    $count->execute();
    $no=$count->rowCount();

    if($no >0 ) {
        echo "User Found";
    } else {
        echo "User Not Found";
    }
}
```

I am guessing I need to sanitize 'serial' to ensure there are no injection attempts. Is there any code to do this for me? Will something like this work?

```
$name = strip_tags(trim( $_POST[ ‘name’ ] ) );
```

Comment: using prepared statements is pretty much the best thing to avoid sql injections, so "your" code is save against such

Comment: Sql-injection impossible here. SQL prepared statements will protect you.

Comment: since you use prepared statements, you dont need to escape the input. The only thing you probably have to do is sanitize the output

Answer (score 1):

If you mean more specifically the [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), then **this statement is good enough to prevent it**, since it uses `prepared statement`, i.e. it passes parameter `:serial` and later on it will fill it by calling `$count->bindParam(":serial",$serial);`.

The risk of SQL Injection is when you make your statement by concatenating SQL queries with user input directly, without sanitization, example:

**DO NOT USE SUCH KIND OF CODING**

```
$count=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE " . $_POST['serial'] .  " LIMIT 1");
```